# Mybatis 3.1 returning only one row in XPATH SQL query

Tags: sql-server, xpath, mybatis

Mybatis 3.1 returning only one row as result of XPATH SQL query, but when running same query in Sql tools like DataGrip/SQLServerManagementStudio its giving 2 rows. I have verified that there are two matching rows as confirmed by running same query in DataGrip. I think there is some issue with mapping to data object or Mybatis not handling XPATH sql correctly.

Mapper Interface:

```
  List<PIIData> getResponseContactInfoPII(@Param("accountIdVal") Long accountIdVal,
                                            @Param("emailVal") String emailVal,
                                            @Param("fNameVal") String fNameVal,
                                            @Param("lNameVal") String lNameVal) throws SQLException;
```

Mapper query:

```
<select id="getResponseContactInfoPII" statementType="CALLABLE" resultMap="piiData" resultType="java.util.List">
  SELECT
      N.x.value('@firstname', 'nvarchar(60)') AS firstName,
      N.x.value('@lastname', 'nvarchar(60)') AS lastName,
      N.x.value('@title', 'nvarchar(60)') AS title,
      N.x.value('@email', 'nvarchar(90)') AS email,
      N.x.value('@phone', 'nvarchar(40)') AS phone,
      'RFP_RESPONSE_CONTACT' as entityName,
      'REF_RFP_OFFERING' as reference,
    CAST(acct_id AS VARCHAR(100)) AS pkCol1,
    CAST(rfp_stub AS VARCHAR(100)) AS pkCol2,
    CAST(ofrg_stub AS VARCHAR(100)) AS pkCol3

    FROM
      (SELECT * FROM dbo.RFP_OFFERING WHERE ofrg_acct_id = #{accountIdVal}) AS RO
  CROSS APPLY
    <choose>
        <when test="fNameVal != null and lNameVal != null">
            RO.response_contact_info_xml.nodes('/ROOT/FIELD[@email="${emailVal}" and @firstname="${fNameVal}" and @lastname="${lNameVal}"]') AS N(x)
        </when>
        <when test="fNameVal != null and lNameVal == null">
            RO.response_contact_info_xml.nodes('/ROOT/FIELD[@email="${emailVal}" and @firstname="${fNameVal}"]') AS N(x)
        </when>
        <when test="fNameVal == null and lNameVal != null">
            RO.response_contact_info_xml.nodes('/ROOT/FIELD[@email="${emailVal}" and @lastname="${lNameVal}"]') AS N(x)
        </when>
        <otherwise>
            RO.response_contact_info_xml.nodes('/ROOT/FIELD[@email="${emailVal}"]') AS N(x)
        </otherwise>
    </choose>
</select>
```

ResultMap:

```
<resultMap id="piiData" type="com.cvent.csngdpr.dbEntity.PIIData">
    <result property = "firstName" column="firstName"/>
    <result property = "lastName" column = "lastName" />
    <result property = "address1" column = "address1" />
    <result property = "address2" column = "address2" />
    <result property = "address3" column = "address3" />
    <result property = "cityName" column = "cityName" />
    <result property = "email" column = "email" />
    <result property = "stateName" column = "stateName" />
    <result property = "countryName" column = "countryName" />
    <result property = "stateCode" column = "stateCode" />
    <result property = "postalCode" column = "postalCode" />
    <result property = "countryCode" column = "countryCode" />
    <result property = "title" column = "title" />
    <result property = "phone" column = "phone" />
    <result property = "mobile" column = "mobile" />
    <result property = "fax" column = "fax" />
    <result property = "ipAddress" column = "ipAddress" />
    <result property = "additionalInfo" column = "additionalInfo" />
    <result property = "zip" column = "zip" />
    <result property = "entityName" column = "entityName" />
    <result property = "reference" column = "reference" />
    <association property="primaryKeys" resultMap="primaryKeysMap"/>
</resultMap>

<resultMap id="primaryKeysMap" type="map">
        <result column="pkCol1" property="pkCol1"/>
        <result column="pkCol2" property="pkCol2"/>
        <result column="pkCol3" property="pkCol3"/>
        <result column="pkCol4" property="pkCol4"/>
        <result column="pkCol5" property="pkCol5"/>
</resultMap>
```

Data Model Object:

```
public class PIIData {

    private String firstName;

    private String lastName;

    private String email;

    private String address1;

    private String address2;

    private String address3;

    private String cityName;

    private String stateName;

    private String countryName;

    private String ipAddress;

    private String entityName;

    private String phone;

    private String mobile;

    private String title;

    private String stateCode;

    private String postalCode;

    private String countryCode;

    private String additionalInfo;

    private String fax;

    private String reference;

    private String zip;

    private Map<String, String> primaryKeys;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Luckily, I found this [link](https://github.com/mybatis/mybatis-3/issues/512) that explains the issue. If all the columns except the association have same values then Mybatis de-duplicates the collection, thats why it was returning only one record.

I just changed resultMap configuration as

Replaced

```
<association property="primaryKeys" resultMap="primaryKeysMap"/>
```

with

```
<result property = "primaryKeys.pkCol1" column = "pkCol1" />
<result property = "primaryKeys.pkCol2" column = "pkCol2" />
<result property = "primaryKeys.pkCol3" column = "pkCol3" />
<result property = "primaryKeys.pkCol4" column = "pkCol4" />
<result property = "primaryKeys.pkCol5" column = "pkCol5" />
```

And removed

```
<resultMap id="primaryKeysMap" type="map">
        <result column="pkCol1" property="pkCol1"/>
        <result column="pkCol2" property="pkCol2"/>
        <result column="pkCol3" property="pkCol3"/>
        <result column="pkCol4" property="pkCol4"/>
        <result column="pkCol5" property="pkCol5"/>
</resultMap>
```

Final configuration:

```
<resultMap id="piiData" type="com.cvent.csngdpr.dbEntity.PIIData">
    <result property = "firstName" column="firstName"/>
    <result property = "lastName" column = "lastName" />
    <result property = "address1" column = "address1" />
    <result property = "address2" column = "address2" />
    <result property = "address3" column = "address3" />
    <result property = "cityName" column = "cityName" />
    <result property = "email" column = "email" />
    <result property = "stateName" column = "stateName" />
    <result property = "countryName" column = "countryName" />
    <result property = "stateCode" column = "stateCode" />
    <result property = "postalCode" column = "postalCode" />
    <result property = "countryCode" column = "countryCode" />
    <result property = "title" column = "title" />
    <result property = "phone" column = "phone" />
    <result property = "mobile" column = "mobile" />
    <result property = "fax" column = "fax" />
    <result property = "ipAddress" column = "ipAddress" />
    <result property = "additionalInfo" column = "additionalInfo" />
    <result property = "zip" column = "zip" />
    <result property = "entityName" column = "entityName" />
    <result property = "reference" column = "reference" />
    <result property = "primaryKeys.pkCol1" column = "pkCol1" />
    <result property = "primaryKeys.pkCol2" column = "pkCol2" />
    <result property = "primaryKeys.pkCol3" column = "pkCol3" />
    <result property = "primaryKeys.pkCol4" column = "pkCol4" />
    <result property = "primaryKeys.pkCol5" column = "pkCol5" />
</resultMap>
```